# Code gets crashed sometimes in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a code. In Which If I enter a excel workbook path in a cell and click on a button then the workbook will be open and the data of current workbook from B2 will be copy and paste into the newly open workbook. The code works well. But the problem is that the code gets crashed and throws an error sometimes. What is the problem i am unable to understand. If the code is not okay then the code will never be execute perfectly. But in my case it is executing well sometimes and sometimes throws an error. Pls help. Here is the error -

**select method of range class failed**

And here is the code -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim pathCell As String

pathCell = Range("locationPath").Value


Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'workbook where the data is to be pasted
Dim wbThis As Workbook 'workbook from where the data is to be copied

'set to the current active workbook (the source book)
Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook

'copy the range from source book
wbThis.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Copy

'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(pathCell)

'Select the target cell
wbTarget.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Select

'paste the data on the target book
wbTarget.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets(1).Activate


End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you click "debug" when it crashes what line is highlighted?

Comment: Your Select line appears to be totally unnecessary and could be deleted. That will likely eliminate the error.

Comment: pathCell = Range("locationPath").Value update the path

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is failing on this line as it is the only one that contains `.Select`

```
'Select the target cell
wbTarget.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Select
```

- That line will fail with the error shown if, at the time it is run, `Worksheets(2)` is not the active sheet. You have to select the worksheet and the range on separate code lines.  That is likely why your macro only errors intermittently. You probably navigate away from that worksheet sometimes before you close the workbook, and not at other times.
- **However**, that does not seem to serve an purpose so far as the Paste operation is concerned, and your paste should work just as well if you delete the line.

  - Your subsequent code line fully qualifies the target cell.

```
'paste the data on the target book
wbTarget.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

If, for some reason, you absolutely need to have that cell selected when the macro completes, first select the worksheet; then select the cell.

Also see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
 on our sister stackoverflow site.